# Обязательность полей ответа Yandex Geocoder

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Подскажите, являются ли элементы ответа Yandex geocoder обязательными?
Например:

```
"featureMember": [
        {
          "GeoObject": {
            "metaDataProperty": {
              "GeocoderMetaData": {
                "kind": "house",
                "text": "Россия, Москва, улица Новый Арбат, 24",
                "precision": "exact",
   ...
```

Может ли вернуться "kind": null?
Может ли массив featureMember быть null?
Это важно, так как пишу на kotlin и не хочется использовать nullable поля для классов, на которые будет мапаться ответ.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если сервис вернёт [ошибку](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/reference/error_codes.html), тогда в ответе не будет нужных вам полей. Но при этом статус-код будет **"statusCode": 400**

Если объекта по запросу найдено не будет, ответ будет пустым массивом - **"featureMember": []**

Если же хоть один ответ есть, блок **[kind](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/reference/kind.html)** показывает тип найденного объекта. В этом случае тип объекта будет или конкретным (**house, street**...) или общим для всего прочего - **other**. Пустым он быть не должен.